# Using a dataframe as input for MLP (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, mlp

I have created/manipulated a large pandas dataframe about flights of the following form:

```
  origin  dep_delay temp    dewp    humid   wind_dir wind_speed visib   late
0   EWR     19.0    39.02   28.04   64.43   260.0    12.65858   10.0     True
1   LGA     4.0     39.92   24.98   54.81   250.0    14.96014   10.0     False
2   JFK     18.0    39.02   26.96   61.63   260.0    14.96014   10.0     True
3   JFK     -8.0    39.02   26.96   61.63   260.0    14.96014   10.0     False
4   LGA     -6.0    39.92   24.98   54.81   260.0    16.11092   10.0     False
```

I would like to use MLP (multi-layer perceptron ideally with tensorflow), to predict which flights will be **late** given the input values of (dep_delay, temp, humid etc.). I think MLP is sensible but let me know if I am mistaken.

I'm not too sure how to approach this as I have only used MLP on images, could anyone help me out?

I know I have to convert the dataframe to a more sensible data type first like a numpy array but I'm not sure how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the type of data you want to prepare and feed your model. The *origin* and *late* columns for example are categorical whilst all the other columns seems to be numerical. One of the many ways to prepare your data is using [keras preprocessing layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers).